# AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer not Displaying B Frames MPEG

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation

So I'm trying to display a mp4 that I'm streaming from the internet. I'm parsing the file correctly (I used http://mp4parser.com) to check that my data was consistent with the proper data. I've run into a bit of an issue though with b-frames. The arrangement of frames in the file is:

```
I P B B P B B P B B
```

I am aware that the B frames require the P frames to be decoded before they can be decoded, so thats why they come after P frames. So from what I understand the playback order should be

```
I B B P B B P B B P
```

My I frames and P frames are displaying correctly, however I am having some trouble with the B frames. When I parse the data from the mp4, they are assigned a 0 duration. So I have two issues, how long they should last for and where to put them exactly (right after the last I or P frame or in the middle between two). The lack of correct placement and duration is causing my 60FPS video to be choppy and inconstant. My current code is a bit of a mess, but here it is (parsing not included because I assume it is correctint

```
total_time = 0;
    int last_times[2] = {0, 0};
    for (int i = 0; i < segment.frames.count; i++) {

        MPEGFrame* frame = [segment.frames objectAtIndex:i];

        CMBlockBufferRef buffer;
        CMBlockBufferCreateWithMemoryBlock(NULL, (void*)[segment.data bytes], [segment.data length], NULL, NULL, frame.absolute_pos, frame.frame_size, 0, &buffer);

        // get time, b frames go before last p-frame
        uint32_t time = total_time;
        if (!frame.frame_time)
            time = last_times[0]; // Maybe this is last_times[0] + (last_times[1] - last_times[0]) / num_b_frames_in_between

        uint32_t duration = frame.frame_time; // B frames this is 0, needs to have correct duration 

        CMSampleTimingInfo timing;
        timing.duration = CMTimeMake(duration, parser.timescale);

        // Guarantee that P and I are decoded before B, if P and I are passed in before, will they be decoded first? 
        timing.decodeTimeStamp = CMTimeMake(last_times[0], parser.timescale);
        timing.presentationTimeStamp = CMTimeMake(time, parser.timescale);

        // If this was an I or a P frame, save position of last P or I and the position of this one
        if (frame.frame_time) {

            last_times[0] = last_times[1];
            last_times[1] = total_time;

        }

        // B frames dont change the total time
        total_time += frame.frame_time;

        CMSampleBufferRef final;
        CMSampleBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, buffer, YES, NULL, NULL, ref, 1, 1, &timing, 0, NULL, &final);

        [layer enqueueSampleBuffer:final];
        NSLog(@"Finished frame");


    }
)
```

I'm not very experienced with video encoding / decoding, but I have watched Apple's WWDC's session on this topic, however they did not provide specifics or example code on how to do this, and I haven't found any on the internet. Any ideas?